# How to compare array from file with sql database query?

Tags: database, perl, file, select, compare

I tried to select all columns from my table at database that is same as on row in array in file. For example:

```
TABLE:
id name
1 A
2 B
3 C

FILE:
A
B
```

I want to select only A and B.

My source:

```
use DBI;
use CGI;    
my $file = '.\input.txt';       # Name the file
    open(FILE, $file) or die("Unable to open file");
    my @data = <FILE>;
    foreach my $line (@data)
    {
      #print $line;
      my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT columnA FROM table WHERE columnA LIKE '%$line%'");
      $sth->execute;
      my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;


      foreach my $row ( @$result ) {
      print "- ";
      print "@$row\n";
      print "<BR />";
      }

     }
```

but it write only last line of select hmmm...

```
OUTPUT I GET

B

OUTPUT I WANT TO GET

A
B
```

I tried it with this:

```
INPUT:
bengalske_stehno
cesnakova_polievka
drzkova_polievka
kuraci_spiz
polievka_fazulova
polievka_mrkvova
polievka_rybacia

DATABASE:
fasirky
cesnakova_polievka
chlebicek_biskupsky
drzkova_polievka
polievka_fazulova
polievka_mrkvova
polievka_rybacia
bengalske_stehno 

OUTPUT:
- polievka_rybacia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you forgot to `chomp $line` after reading from the input file. The newline is not present on the last line in the file, that's why it works.

Comment: thank you very much it is what i forgot

Comment: Can i ask you how to select only one row??? and it can be also random row??? I tried ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 but it nothing changed

Comment: rowid = (abs(random()) % (select max(rowid)+1 from recepty))

Comment: no it isnt good because it choose sometimes more than one row hmmmm do you have some better solution? or I have to ask a question?

Comment: @TomasKocian: Yes, better to ask a new question as it does not seem related to the original problem.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669158/select-one-random-row-from-cycle-of-function-with-sqlite-and-perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669158/select-one-random-row-from-cycle-of-function-with-sqlite-and-perl)