# Select one random row from cycle of function with SQLite and Perl

Tags: database, perl, sqlite, select

Hi I tried to select one random number from this:

My source:

```
use DBI;
use CGI; 

my $file = '.\input.txt';       # Name the file
open(FILE, $file) or die("Unable to open file");
my @data = <FILE>;
foreach my $line (@data)
{
  chomp $line
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT columnA FROM table WHERE columnA LIKE '%$line%'");
  $sth->execute;
  my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;


  foreach my $row ( @$result ) {
  print "- ";
  print "@$row\n";
  print "<BR />";
  }

 }
```

How can I print only ONE RANDOM row???
I tried something like that:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT nazov_receptu FROM recepty WHERE nazov_receptu LIKE '%$line%' AND kategoria == 'p' AND (rowid = (abs(random()) % (select max(rowid)+1 from recepty)) or rowid = (select max(rowid) from recepty)) order by rowid limit 1;");
```

but its not clear... i dont know why...

I am using SQLite and printing it to web interface.

You can try it when you have 
input.txt:

```
A
C
```

database:

```
id name
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

OUT:

```
A OR C (random)
```

Comment: SQLite has a random function, just stick "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1" to the end of your query and you should get 1 random row

Comment: nothing changed... it print me all rows... not one... 
try it with cgi and dbi and clause WHERE...

Comment: Show the query statement please. `order by random() limit 1` does work.

Comment: Yes, you have a problem in your query, the random doesn't even matter in terms of the number of rows, the "limit 1" is going to only return 1 row regardless so if you are getting all rows then that isn't in there.

Comment: `SELECT columnA FROM table WHERE columnA LIKE '%$line%' order by random() limit 1`.  Is that what you have?

Comment: The query is executed many times, as many times as there are lines in the text file; it is inside a loop.  `foreach my $line (@data)`.

Comment: yes query is executed many times... and I want only one result... how should i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not join the file arguments into the query right away instead of looping over them? Then it is a simple matter to extract a random index in perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;                            # Always use these two pragmas

my $file   = '.\input.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Unable to open file: $!";
chomp(my @data = <$fh>);                # chomp all lines at once
my $query  = "SELECT columnA FROM table WHERE ";
$query    .= join " OR ", ( "columnA LIKE ?" ) x @data;
                                         # add placeholder for each line
@data = map "%$_%", @data;               # add wildcards
my $sth    = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(@data);                    # execute query with lines as argument
my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
my $randid = rand @$result;              # find random index
my $row    = $result->[ $randid ];
print "- @$row\n";
print "<BR />";
```

As you see, I've used [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values), which is the proper way to use variables with queries. It also happens to be a simple way to handle an arbitrary amount of arguments. Because we include all lines in the query, we do not need a `for` loop.

As you see, I've also changed a few other small details, such as using three argument `open` with a lexical file handle, including the error variable `$!` in the `die` statement, using proper indentation, using `strict` and `warnings` (you should never code without them)

I've handled the randomization in perl because it is simplest for me. It may be as simple and more effective to handle in the SQL query. You may just tack on the `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1` to the end of it, and that might work just fine too.

Comment: DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: near " ": syntax error at C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/bc/expert.pl line 102, line 7. , 
LINE 102: my $sth    = $dbh->prepare($query);

Comment: That's a very non-helpful error. Syntax error next to a space, not very precise indication where it is. Perhaps your DB can't handle trailing spaces. Try removing the spaces in `"columnA LIKE?"`

Comment: I write this: what is wrong?

my $query  = "SELECT nazov_receptu FROM recepty WHERE ";
     $query    .= join " OR ", ("nazov_receptu LIKE?") x @data;

Comment: It should be `LIKE ?`. You know, if you read the documentation I provided this would be clear to you.

Comment: That's why it is important to read documentation. There's lots of examples there too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30343/discussion-between-tomas-kocian-and-tlp)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `order by random()`,

```
SELECT nazov_receptu FROM recepty ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to fetch only one random row, make sure to put this code out of the loop,

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT nazov_receptu FROM recepty ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1");
$sth->execute;
my ($nazov_receptu) = $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

Comment: nothing changed... it print me all rows... not one... try it with cgi and dbi and clause WHERE...

Comment: How many random rows do you need? Put sql query outside of `foreach` loop if you need just one.

Comment: I need only one row... how to print it without for each?

Answer (score 1):

Because your query is inside the `foreach my $line (@data)` loop, it will run once for each item in `@data`, getting a different random row each time.  If you want it to only run once total, you need to move it outside of that loop (in addition to using "order by random() limit 1").